# Google calendar multiple calendars

Tags: google-calendar

I invited someone to share a calendar but when she clicked on the link the new calendar appeared to be merged with her already existing calednar and she freaked out because she thinks everyone can see her schedule. How can you keep it separated?

For some stupid reason for her calendar, even when I uncheck her personal one under "my calendars" and only have the shared one under "other calendars" everytime she adds or modifies an event her personal caledar gets shown again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you get your friend to double check if she is putting events into the correct calendar? There is an option to choose what calendar to create an event in during event creation time.